# How to show two maps in a single page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to add two google maps on single page of my website, but it displays on existing map. How to add two google maps one by one on singe page?

here is the code....

```html
<div class="map">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <div style="overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:1600px;">
    <div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:400px;width:1130px;">
    </div>
    <style>
      #gmap_canvas img {
        max-width: none!important;
        background: none!important
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function init_map() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 18,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.968203873914659, 79.39677137070021),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(10.968203873914659, 79.39677137070021)
        });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "<b>Code Shoppy</b><br/>Vatti pilaiyar Koil Road<br/>Upstairs of Chola Ceramics<br/>Kumbakonam-612001"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
    </script>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>

  <div style="overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:600px;">
    <div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:500px;width:600px;"></div>
    <style>
      #gmap_canvas img {
        max-width: none!important;
        background: none!important
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function init_map() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.7904833, 78.70467250000002),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(10.7904833, 78.70467250000002)
        });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "<b>Power Integrated Solutions</b><br/>10A/3 Radhkrishnan Colony, Sasthri Road,<br/> Trichy-17"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        nfowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a problem in your code at line ... hmmm, no code

Answer (score 1):

You have two divs with `id="gmap_canvas"`

id's **MUST** be unique in HTML or bad things happen

Comment: removed or changed ... removed = bad, changed **ALL** the second references to something else ... and I mean **ALL** in that second "block", then something else is wrong

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

1. you're loading the Google maps API twice, which is not necessary
2. using the same id `id="gmap_canvas"` for both maps
3. definig the function `init_map` twice

I modified your code assigning `id="gmap_canvas2"` to the second map, calling the init function for the second map `init_map2` and loading the Google maps Javascript only once at the beginning.

```js
function init_map() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.968203873914659, 79.39677137070021),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas2"), myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(10.968203873914659, 79.39677137070021)
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<b>Code Shoppy</b><br/>Vatti pilaiyar Koil Road<br/>Upstairs of Chola Ceramics<br/>Kumbakonam-612001"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);

function init_map2() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.7904833, 78.70467250000002),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(10.7904833, 78.70467250000002)
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<b>Power Integrated Solutions</b><br/>10A/3 Radhkrishnan Colony, Sasthri Road,<br/> Trichy-17"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map2);
```

```css
#gmap_canvas img {
  max-width: none!important;
  background: none!important
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>

First map
<div class="map">
  <div style="overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:1600px;">
    <div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:400px;width:1130px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Second map
<div class="container">
  <div style="overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:600px;">
    <div id="gmap_canvas2" style="height:500px;width:600px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```